# Spatial checking for 2 polygons intersect in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I want to check source building intersect with target building (source buildings 150000 & target buildings 150000) this is very heavy data.

i have use(Spatial Filter)(ITopologicalOperator.intersect)(IRelational Operator) also it is take more time for running if any other way to check spatial intersection in C# ArcObjects

Answer (score 1):

The [ITopologicalOperator.Intersect()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Intersect_Method/002m000003vs000000/) method *constructs* the geometry of the intersection. In you question you are talking about *testing* if geometries intersect not constructing the result of the intersection.

I would look at the Interface [IProximityOperator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000031w000000) and the ReturnDistance method, a zero indicating they intersect.